# There are 50 students in a class who are given a test with 3 questions on it: $Q_1$, $Q_2$, and $Q_3$. All the students answer at least one question…

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I am trying to solve the following question:

> There are $50$ students in a class who are given a test with $3$ questions on it: $Q_1$, $Q_2$, and $Q_3$. All the students answer at least $1$ question. If $12$ students did not answer $Q_1$, $14$ did not answer $Q_2$, $10$ did not answer $Q_3$ and $25$ answered all $3$ questions, then how many students answered exactly $1$ question?

So I define $3$ sets as such:

- Students who answered $Q_1 = A$
- Students who answered $Q_2 = B$
- Students who answered $Q_3 = C$

I am given the following:

- $|A \cup B \cup C| = 50$
- $|B \cup C \cap A^c| = 12$ (Students who did not answer $Q_1$)
- $|A \cup C \cap B^c| = 14$ (Students who did not answer $Q_2$)
- $|A \cup B \cap C^c)| = 10$ (Students who did not answer $Q_3$)
- $|A \cap B \cap C| = 25$ (Students who answered all $3$)

The principle of Inclusion-Exclusion states that:
$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A ∩ B| - |A ∩ C| - |B ∩ C| + |A ∩ B ∩ C|$$

Substituting for the knows values:

$$50 = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A ∩ B| - |A ∩ C| - |B ∩ C| + 25$$

Or $$25 = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A ∩ B| - |A ∩ C| - |B ∩ C|$$

But now I am stuck because the statement above does not give me any information about students who answered exactly 1 question.

**How do I move ahead or where did I go wrong?
I dont want to know the answer, I just want to know how to proceed.**

Since I got stuck there I went ahead and defined $3$ more sets:

- Students who answered exactly $1$ question = $D$
- Students who answered exactly $2$ questions = $E$
- Students who answered exactly $3$ questions = $F$

I know that $|F| = 25$

and $|D \cup E \cup F| = 50$

But now I am stuck again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to flesh out @turkeyhundt's method, which is basically what you've started out writing. Here's a Venn diagram to clarify what variable I'll assign to which question:

[image]

---

We're given the following:

$$a+b+c + x+y+z=25$$

$$b+c+z=12$$

$$a+c+x=14$$

$$a+b+y=10$$

We're trying to find $a+b+c$. If we add the second, third, and fourth equations above we get

$$2a+2b+2c+x+y+z=36$$

Subtracting the first equation above gives us the desired result

$$a+b+c = \boxed{11}$$

---

Notice that it's not possible to find the individual values of $a$, $b$, and $c$, but it's also not necessary to do that in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I was over thinking this problem :/

Answer (score 3):

25 students answer all three questions hence 25 students answered one or two questions, as no student didn't answer any question. But we know that there are 12 + 14 + 10 = 36 unanswered questions in total.  Hence 11 of the 25 students didn't answer two questions, as 25 + 11 = 36.

Therefore 11 answered one question; 25 - 11 = 14 answered two questions.

Comment: This is probably better than my brute force method.

Comment: @turkeyhundt It's actually the exact same thing, but you don't need all seven of your equations - only four of them ...

Answer (score 2):

You can set up 7 linear equations.
Let's let "A only" = a

B only = b

C only = c

A and B only = x

B and C only = z

C and A only = y

then

$b+c+z=12$

$a+x+y=13$

$a+y+c=14$

$b+x+z=11$

$a+x+b=10$

$y+c+z=15$

$a+b+c+x+y+z=25$